# Finding specific letters in a text file and returning that as a string with my name to be placed in label control VB2010

Tags: vb.net

I have a project where I have to find the letters of my name in a given text file in VB2010 and return those letters using string manipulation techniques as my name into a label control.

I have looked at several youtube videos and looked around the web. Some recommend putting the text file into an array. Some others are just for one specific word (Which my name isn't in the text file as a word). So I really haven't found anything to suit my needs.

I know the code needs to placed in the event load form.

I've only been at VB for 7 weeks, so I am novice.

Any tips or hints are appreciated. If further explanation needed please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: So where are you stuck? Are you stuck on searching the string?  Are you stuck on putting the letters into a control?  What "string manipulation techniques" are you supposed to be using?  Are you supposed to count the occurrence of each letter of your name in the file?  Are you supposed to just stop once you have found each letter of your name?  It is not clear to me what you are stuck on or need help doing.

Comment: The teacher said to use string manipulation, which in the text book I have not found anything that relates to this. I need it to stop once I have found each letter in my name. Where I am stuck is how to get it to read the text file and return the letters.

Comment: Start out by reading the text file, look at each character for each letter. when you find each letter - stop. Basic file read, string matching, and looping.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we won't do your homework for you, but here's a HOWTO on reading a text file in VB.NET.  It's a good starting point.

[How to: Read Text from a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look up regular expressions. This should help you with the parsing of the text file.